# Using the infinitive or past tense for the verb for a future event

Tags: grammar

A recent article in The New Yorker included this phrase: "...forbade him to represent Israel in bridge for an additional 18 months...". I would have written " forbade him from representing Israel". Which is correct, and why?

Comment: @jimm101 The alternative here is not a gerund, it's a prepositional phrase that includes a gerund.

Comment: Nice question I saw OracleOfNewJersey already asked....

Answer (score -2):

As it's *"to forbid to"*, here *to* is fine ; it's just a question of language but you can either prevent **from**.

Concerning *"forbid someone [from ?] doing something"* and *"forbid him **to** do it"*, as the restriction is enacted from above - *ie.* in the normative order - to the subject, on purpose to prohibit the active behavior of this one **on** something **or to do** something, the prohibition does not emanate *from* what is forbidden itself. So you may find "forbid *from"* doing something but it's not correct. (& for my part, *"forbid from"* is worst than *"prevent to"*, which is neither correct.)

Expressions of prevention, prohibition, banning, exclusion or stopping actions take *gerund-participle complements in PPs headed by* **from**. The verbs are :

1. ban,
2. hinder,
3. keep,
4. prevent,
5. prohibit &
6. stop.

I guess to "forbid *from*" could derive from such verbs but *to forbid* isn't in that list *(cf. Cambridge Grammar, last ed. p. 835 in fine.)*

So it is not to "forbid *from*" (...) but only in correct AmE **to forbid to** ; however in InE (idianEnglish) I'd catch the sense :)

Comment: I don't see why it's relevant to OP's question, but in what context is ***prevent to*** valid?

Comment: to is more usual but we find : that prevent to find common solutions ; prevent to happen again ; prevent to disclose etc.

Comment: That's not a usage I've ever come across. [Nothing in NGrams,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prevented+it+being%2Cprevented+it+to+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprevented%20it%20being%3B%2Cc0), and while OED says that   *prevent + gerund* without ***from*** has sometimes been criticized as incorrect, they don't mention the possibility of using ***to*** instead. Is it "Indian English"?

Comment: Prevent from should be the sole right form in modern English. But prevent to is "affordable" with no need to pay a ticket for Bombay. (Take notice guys, I add "to" because I thought someone would have requested it...)

Comment: I've just trawled through the 80% of OED usages marked "obsolete" - so far as I can see, *prevent **to*** was never "valid". It never had any currency either. As I write, nobody has cared enough about either the question or the answer to cast an upvote, so I'll start the ball rolling with a downvote because I think it's misleading to suggest this usage is in any way credible.

Comment: I never suggested this usage but only mentioned it... But if you'd rather like this I may edit my answer on purpose to cancel the 2 last words because I never use this form & am always reluctant when I see it. So just tell me...

Comment: That's the only reason for my downvote, so if you remove those last two words I'll happily cancel it. But I won't *upvote* because I don't think you've meaningfully addressed the usages *forbid someone [**from**] doing something* and *forbid him **to** do it*, as asked about by the OP.

Comment: OK I edit because I add "to" to cover the full range of (ill-)options

Comment: Do you have any reference that says *forbid him from verb-ing* is ungrammatical? I would have thought the two grammatical options were *forbid him to verb* and *forbid him from verb-ing*.

Comment: No as "Forbid to" is fine ! But "forbid from" should be replaced by "prevent from" if you need "from". Here the gramma joins the normative point : You're not forbidden from something but by a positive prescription, which rules the case, to do what is not allowed.

Comment: I found the gramma reason in a gramma book ; so I edited my previous answer....